# Program needed for PDF Manipulation

Tags: pdf

I need a program to create/stack and print PDFs.  What program can do this for me?

Comment: You really should give a bit more info. For instance, any program can create PDFs using a PDF print driver. What does stacking PDFs mean? And any PDF reader software, like Acrobat, can print PDFs.

Comment: ScanSoft PaperPort calls it "unstacking" when you split a multi-page PDF into single-page items, and "stacking" when you combine single items into a multi-page PDF.  I think by "print PDFs" Dan means saving a file in PDF format (which is usually done by installing a PDF printer).

Comment: Try asking at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. Btw. Adobe Acrobat software is designed for PDF file manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [PDFill PDF Tools Free](http://www.pdfill.com/pdf_tools_free.html), which also includes a free PDF printer.  It lets you concatenate, split, and reorder PDF files.  You can also perform a lot of other operations, as you can see from the screen shot:

[image: PDFill screenshot]

If you have a scanner that came with ScanSoft PaperPort, you can probably also use that to merge/split (stack/unstack) your PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

I purchased and use Nitro PDF
http://www.nitropdf.com

I have been very pleased with it for the price.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from PDF reader, Adobe has always distributed [Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatstd/) for creating PDF files, which is now part of Adobe CS suite, but there are cheaper alternatives like [FoxIt](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/) which has both reader and editing alternatives. For most options, you'd probably want Adobe Acrobat, but depending on your needs FoxIt and alternatives might do what you want at much cheaper price.

Also, keep in mind that you usually don't "create" PDF files - you mostly "print out" PDF files from software in which you created your document (like Microsoft Word or Excel or basically anything else).

Answer (score 0):

Try [**PDFTools**](http://www.sheelapps.com/index.php?p=PDFTools.HomePage&action=view) from Sheelapps. It's free and lets you *"encrypt, decrypt, join, split, stamp, create and rearrange a PDF file."*